# Editing Pages Icons Are Not Showing Up - Why is this happening?

Tags: pages, bug

https://prnt.sc/pgoou9 - check it out
https://prnt.sc/pgop70 - here too.
https://prnt.sc/pgopeo - however putting the mouse above them shows their function but still...
How can we fix this situation, I really don't know if I did something to make it like that or it was like that ever since the start.

Appreciate your time!

Comment: It looks like dashicons or some other part of WP Admin has been dequeued or not loading, it's not possible to debug though with just screenshots or without direct access to the site. Have you raised this as an issue with the gutenberg team/WP Core? Follow the usual debugging steps of disabling everything then turning it on 1 by 1 until the problem returns to identify what's causing it

Comment: Also try reinstalling WP core, replace everything except for the wp-content folder with a freshly downloaded WP.